# Filtering a 'null' ID in Talend. Using a tFilterRow

Tags: java, talend

I am using Talend to migrate information into Salesforce. As of right now, when running the job I receive an error- "java.lang.Exception: attempted to add a campaign member where either the member id '0033700009Ms49' or the campaign id 'null' is null.

Now, I put down a tFilterRow to filter out any campaign Id that is equal to 'null' and any contact Id that is equal to 'null'. I even put the specific ID that appeared in the error log. Could anyone point me in the right direction? I am beyond stumped.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some screenshots of the settings and your job.

Comment: what you can do for now is to remove this filter and add tFileDelimitedoutput component and make your data flow to this component. this will product a flat file which all data and you can verify which campaignid or contact is null. Next you add tfilterrow component before tfileoutputdelimited and then add filter condition to remove null rows and again test data getting written to flat file..this way you can play more with your filter conditions and see what is getting filtered and what not..you can explore trim() string length() functions and filter rows where length() <=0